How to create a custom list with a dynamic background that vertically moves downwards when there are new items?


I have created the background using a shape struct called VectorShape and created a func path that draws out the VectorShape. Below is the code:
import SwiftUI

struct VectorShape: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
                var path = Path()
                let width = rect.size.width
                let height = rect.size.height
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.083771389*width, y: 0.0048507464*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0625162683*width, y: 0.0048507464*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0579251837*width, y: 0.0703358247*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.0548233261*width, y: 0.0097014928*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.058639587*width, y: 0.0562963474*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0625162683*width, y: 0.7512437811*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0.0565676091*width, y: 0.0970149301*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.0625162683*width, y: 0.5410447761*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.7512437811*height))
                path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0021402598*width, y: 1.3582089552*height), control1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.7512437811*height), control2: CGPoint(x: 0.0021406803*width, y: 1.1144278607*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.083771389*width, y: 1.3582089552*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.7362637363*width, y: 1.3582089552*height))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.7362637363*width, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.083771389*width, y: 0.0048507464*height))
                path.closeSubpath()
                return path
        }
}

#Preview{

    VectorShape().fill().frame(width: 273, height: 201)

}

Currently, I am not sure:

How do I contain and create a list within the VectorShape and make the list dynamic such that the VectorShape vertically moves downwards when there are new items in the list

I have tried several ideas such as creating a zstack, and then within the zstack, I added my Vector shape and a vstack for the list section. However, the list would not be contained within the VectorShape. Hence, I am not sure how to make the list dynamic such that the VectorShape vertically moves downwards as there are new items in the list. Do I need to use another software for the dynamic part?
Below is what I have done as a structure:
import SwiftUI

struct ChecklistItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var isChecked: Bool
    
}

struct ChecklistTest: View {
    
    @State private var checklistItems = [
            ChecklistItem(title: "Item 1", isChecked: false),
            ChecklistItem(title: "Item 2", isChecked: false),
            ChecklistItem(title: "Item 3", isChecked: false)
        ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            VectorShape()
                .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.96009022, blue: 0.8565915227, alpha: 1)))
                .stroke(.black)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            
            VStack {
                ForEach($checklistItems) { $item in
                    HStack {
                                    
                        Text(item.title)
                                    
                        Spacer()
                                    
                        Image(systemName: item.isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                item.isChecked.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                    .padding(5)
                                
                    if item.id != checklistItems.last?.id {
                        Divider()
                            .overlay(.black)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 280, height: 150, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.top, 60)
                                           
        }
    
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ChecklistTest()
}


First, fix the drawing code for the shape so that the height of the "sticking out" part does not depend on the height of the shape. Here I added a parameter to the shape, so that callers can pass in a fixed height for the "sticking out" part.
struct VectorShape: Shape {
    let insetHeight: CGFloat
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // Here I simply subtracting a smaller rectangle from 'rect'
        Path(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 0)
            .subtracting(
                Path(
                    roundedRect: .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width / 2, height: insetHeight),
                    cornerRadius: 0
                )
            )
        // More customisable ways to draw this shape is out of the scope of this question
    }
}

Second, remove all the height: parameters you pass to .frame. We want a dynamic height after all.
Third, use the shape as a background of the VStack, so that its size matches the size of the VStack.
VStack {
    VStack {
        // I have added invisible dividers to the top and bottom of the list,
        // so that the first and last items look better
        Divider().opacity(0)
        ForEach($checklistItems) { $item in
            HStack {
                Text(item.title)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: item.isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        item.isChecked.toggle()
                    }
            }
            .padding(5)
            Divider()
                .overlay(.black)
                .opacity(item.id != checklistItems.last?.id ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 280, alignment: .leading)
    .padding(.top, 40)
    .background(.gray, in: VectorShape(insetHeight: 40)) // the shape is used here!
    
    Spacer()
    
    // I've also added a button to add new items
    Button("Add Item") {
        checklistItems.append(.init(title: "New Item", isChecked: false))
    }
}

